# Unable to convert json string to json object

Tags: ios, json, swift, string, serialization

```
let dictionaryToJsonObject: [String: Any]

let Dictionary: [String: Any] = ["FirstName": "John", "Email": "Jo@sm.com", "Password": "john@123", "LastName": "Smith", "Organization": ["Type": 5, "Name": "IT"]]

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: Dictionary as Any, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let jsonText = String(data: jsonData,
                          encoding: .ascii)

    print("JSON string = \(jsonText!)")

    if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonText!) {
        print("Valid")
    } else {
        print("Not Valid")
    }

}catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Output Will be : -

```
JSON string = {
  "FirstName" : "John",
  "Email" : "Jo@sm.com",
  "Password" : "john@123",
  "LastName" : "Smith",
  "Organization" : {
    "Type" : 5,
    "Name" : "IT"
  }
}
```

expected Result :

```
{   
    FirstName:"John",
    Email:"Jo@sm.com",
    Password:"john@123",
    LastName:"Smith",
    Organization:{
        Type:5,
        Name:"IT"
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference in both results ? and why .ascii encoding ? you should use utf8 encoding when converting data to string!

Comment: `encoding: .ascii` — why are you doing this? It's encoded in UTF8. They have only first 128 characters in common.

Comment: @Lion Output is in string Json formate and expected one is in json object formate is it possible or not

Comment: @user28434 yes that will be UTF8

Comment: @SanjayMishra, will be? Why not just edit it now? Also, it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7562206/sanjay-mishra) your account?

Comment: @SanjayMishra : You are converting your data to json string! If you want result in object form then you should convert it in json object! refer my answer! But ultimately it will be your dictionary nothing else!

Comment: Yeah That's I have written already! But check he is declaring Dictionary as array so If he will print dictionary then he will not able to get it in object format. So I thing json serialization is required for his case! @user28434

Comment: @Lion, well it's `Dictionary<String, Any>`, not array, and converting back and forth will return the same dictionary. I bet `==` for input and output will be the same.

Comment: Also, this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279175/i-want-to-convert-this-dictionary-into-json-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get it in json object form then your code should be like,

```
  let dictionaryToJsonObject: [String: Any]

    let Dictionary: [String: Any] = ["FirstName": "John", "Email": "Jo@sm.com", "Password": "john@123", "LastName": "Smith", "Organization": ["Type": 5, "Name": "IT"]]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: Dictionary as Any, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .init(rawValue: 0))


        print("JSON string = \(jsonObject)")

        if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObject) {
            print("Valid")
        } else {
            print("Not Valid")
        }

    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

and your output will be,

```
JSON string = {
Email = "Jo@sm.com";
FirstName = John;
LastName = Smith;
Organization =     {
    Name = IT;
    Type = 5;
};
    Password = "john@123";
}
Valid
```

Ultimately it is your declared dictionary itself I think!

Comment: @Line Yes your right i already did this solution but the api expecting value as string formate like above i mention. Can u please tell me any solution to get the expected output

Comment: Are you using any library for communication to server ? or are you directly using `NSURLSession` methods ?

Comment: Doing a round trip through `JSONSerialization` is pointless – if you just want to print the dictionary as an `NSDictionary`, just say `print(dictionary as NSDictionary)`. This is *not* JSON though.

Comment: @SanjayMishra You need to use a different encoder than `JSONSerialization` then, because the format your API is expecting isn't JSON. You shouldn't rely on `NSDictionary`'s printing style either for that, as that's an implementation detail.